# using json data with jQuery Highcharts Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, csv

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // define the options
            var options = {

                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container'
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Daily visits at www.highcharts.com'
                },

                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    labels: {
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 3,
                        y: -3 
                    }
                },

                yAxis: [{ // left y axis
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    labels: {
                        align: 'left',
                        x: 3,
                        y: 16,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                        }
                    },
                    showFirstLabel: false
                }, { // right y axis
                    linkedTo: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 0,
                    opposite: true,
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    labels: {
                        align: 'right',
                        x: -3,
                        y: 16,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                        }
                    },
                    showFirstLabel: false
                }],

                legend: {
                    align: 'left',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 20,
                    floating: true,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },

                tooltip: {
                    shared: true,
                    crosshairs: true
                },

                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                click: function() {
                                    hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                        pageOrigin: {
                                            x: this.pageX, 
                                            y: this.pageY
                                        },
                                        headingText: this.series.name,
                                        maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+ 
                                            this.y +' visits',
                                        width: 200
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        marker: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    }
                },

                series: [{
                    name: 'All visits',
                    lineWidth: 4,
                    marker: {
                        radius: 4
                    }
                }, {
                    name: 'New visitors'
                }]
            }

            // Load data asynchronously using jQuery. On success, add the data
            // to the options and initiate the chart.
            // This data is obtained by exporting a GA custom report to TSV.
            // http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
            jQuery.get('analytics.tsv', null, function(tsv) {
                var lines = [],
                    listen = false,
                    date,

                    // set up the two data series
                    allVisits = [],
                    newVisitors = [];

                try {
                // split the data return into lines and parse them
                tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {

                    // listen for data lines between the Graph and Table headers
                    if (tsv[i - 3] == '# Graph') {
                        listen = true;
                    } else if (line == '' || line.charAt(0) == '#') {
                        listen = false;
                    }

                    // all data lines start with a double quote
                    if (listen) {
                        line = line.split(/\t/);
                        date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');

                        allVisits.push([
                            date, 
                            parseInt(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                        ]);
                        newVisitors.push([
                            date, 
                            parseInt(line[2].replace(',', ''), 10)
                        ]);
                    }
                });
                } catch (e) { alert(e.message) }
                options.series[0].data = allVisits;
                options.series[1].data = newVisitors;

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });

        });

    </script>
```

above is an example code for jquery plugin 'highcharts', i am trying to get the data from a json file if the json string is as: 
         {
            name: 'allVisits',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
         }, {
            name: 'newVisits',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
         }

the example file is getting the data from a 'tsv' file so i am trying to get the data from the json file instead.

Comment: You have a date item in each line of the tsv file, but you don't have any date in the JSON data. So where should the date come from for each entry, or how should the `allVisits` and `newVisitors` arrays look like instead?